# Perrmission to run specific command by sudo as www-data users without password

Tags: php, permissions, exec, sudoers

I have a webserver that also plays internet radio. As www-data user I want to run some commands, for example I've made this in */etc/sudoers* file:

```
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/amixer
```

And form PHP I can manipulate volume without using password by:

```
exec('sudo -u user amixer set Master 3%-');
```

And:

```
exec('sudo -u user amixer set Master 3%+');
```

But now I want to be able to restart my own service by runing command:

```
exec('sudo -u user service servicename restart');
```

So I tried:

```
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/amixer, NOPASSWD: /bin/service
```

And this:

```
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/amixer, /bin/service
```

And even this:

```
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/amixer
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/service
```

But none of them seems to be working. Please help me out.

---

Sorry guys - my mistake. I've done some changes, tried to link form /sbin to /bin

Now I have changed it to:

```
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/amixer, NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

And it works! Thanks!
Topic closed.

Comment: `service servicename restart` doesn't seem to be the same as `/bin/service` is guess. you could try to put the restart call in a shell script and then allow sudo to call that script.

Comment: You can find where binaries are using the `which` command in a shell. In this case `which service` will tell you where it is - at a guess it'll be in `/sbin` rather than `/bin`.

Comment: @Peter if the question is closed, you should click "close" below the question…

Comment: Feeela thanks but I see only "share", "edit", "delete" and "flag".
Can't see "close" button

Comment: @Feela: close votes on own questions require 250+ reputation.

Answer (score 6):

Careful with your solution: you can start, stop or restart any service that way!

Better create a shell script that runs this command:

```
echo "#!/bin/sh' > /usr/bin/amixer_restart
echo "sudo -u user service amixer restart' >> /usr/bin/amixer_restart
```

Grant adequate permissions (550 mean root and group www-data can read and execute, nobody can write)

```
sudo chown root:www-data /usr/bin/amixer_restart
sudo chmod 550 /usr/bin/amixer_restart
```

And allow apache to sudo on this script:

```
www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/amixer_restart
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing:

1. Install apache2 by running `sudo apt-get install apache2`
2. Make sure apache is allowed to run cgi scripts by running `sudo a2enmod cgi`
3. Restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`
4. Verify that I can run bash scripts by creating the following script at `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # get today's date
   OUTPUT="$(date)"
   USR=$(whoami)

   # headers
   echo "Content-type: text/plain"
   echo ""

   # body
   echo "Today is $OUTPUT"
   echo "Current user is $USR"
   ```
5. make the script executable `chmod +x /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.sh`
6. Verify I am able to execute the script `curl localhost/cgi-bin/test.sh` I get back the following response:

   ```
    Today is Wed Sep  6 12:19:34 PDT 2017 
    Current user is www-data
   ```
7. Because the user is www-data I then add that user as a sudoer. I then modify the file  `/etc/sudoers` by adding this line at the end:

   `www-data                ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
8. Now that user is supposed to have root privileges. Then I modify my test.sh script as:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # get today's date
   OUTPUT="$(date)"
   USR=$(sudo whoami)
   ```
9. Then you should see the following response when executing a get request agains `localhost/cgi-bin/test.sh`:

   ```
   Today is Wed Sep  6 12:28:38 PDT 2017
   Current user is root
   ```